# How can I invoke the driver Settings dialog for a printer

Tags: delphi

Rather than use the standard PrintDialog I am building my own dialog.
I want to be able to invoke the Printer driver's own Setup dialog i.e. as if one had clicked on the Properties button from the PrintDialog.
Can you suggest a method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used this API before, but it seems to me like you can use the [`DocumentProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/documentproperties) function for this.

A minimal example (using the default printer):

```
var
  PrinterName: string;
  BufLen: Cardinal;
  PrinterHandle: THandle;
begin

  GetDefaultPrinter(nil, @BufLen);
  SetLength(PrinterName, BufLen);
  GetDefaultPrinter(PChar(PrinterName), @BufLen);
  SetLength(PrinterName, BufLen - 1);

  if not OpenPrinter(PChar(PrinterName), PrinterHandle, nil) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Could not open printer.');
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    DocumentProperties(Handle, PrinterHandle, PChar(PrinterName), nil, nil, DM_IN_PROMPT)
    // possibly do other things that might raise an exception
  finally
    ClosePrinter(PrinterHandle);
  end;
```

The `nil` pointers can be replaced by `DEVMODE` structures that contain the initial settings and the settings selected by the user in the GUI, if you also add the corresponding flags. See the documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you have nailed it.  I had glossed over DocumentProperies because I assumed it referred to the documenyt rather than the Printer.

Comment: Of course: only printing "could not open printer" is unnecessarily holding back details to the user. Always issue `GetLastError` and serve the appropriate message. `GetDefaultPrinter` can also fail the same way.